# Developing a New Software Application in Chess

Tags: software

What software application do you think that does not exist? I'm a programmer and I would like to implement it to help the Chess world. Thanks in advance to those who give me good ideas.

Comment: Scratch your own itch.  If you need it yourself it will most likely be better than if you have no personal interest in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it already exists, but a cell phone app to scan diagrams and chess notation from books and then store the information in a database in a re-playable format would be handy.

Comment: +1 There is indeed no such app. There are apps for 2D diagrams in Android, but not exactly everything you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give some nice applications, but I'm not sure if you'll have the skills...

- Automatically annotate a chess game with natural language processing, like how a human coach would do. I'm not talking about a blunder check, but a *full* annotated game.
- Port Komodo or Houdini to the iOS platform
- A website that can analyze a chess website (eg: Chessbase), extract the diagrams and give back analysis
- A website that I can analyze a chess position in FEN. There're several that can do that, but they are very limited. I'm looking for a complete package like Chessbase.
- Given a single chess game, estimate the ELO rating
- Extend deep learning and use it to make a new engine that can consistently beat Stockfish
- A chess engine that can speak and coach you for chess
- Train a convolutional deep neutral network that can recognize a board position in a YouTube video (Google can already do that for face detection)

Comment: A tablebase up to 10 pieces is unrealistic because 2012 university moscow created a tablebase for all 7 piece positions and it had 140 Terabyte of disk space

Comment: @don of course I know it's unrealistic but the question was about what application don't exist.

Comment: and in the same question he says: I would like to implement it :-)

Answer (score 0):

A program that can convert PDF chess book files to PGN or CBH format.